# Python 3.4 - Using a FOR loop and want to use a button to increment the loop

Tags: python, button, for-loop

Here is the code. I'm trying to have the loop "pause" and wait for the button press before incrementing.  Basically, the label will say "1 of 5" and when you click the button, the label should change to "2 of 5",etc.  As it is, it doesn't wait for the button and just keeps looping, so the label just says "5 of 5".  I assume I need some "command=" for the button but can't figure out what.
New to Python.  Appreciate any advice.

```
for a in range (0,total_kegs):
        kegstr= str(a+1)+" of "+ str(total_kegs)
        Label(Fill_frame, text=kegstr).grid(row=3,column=1)
        Start_fill_button = Button(Fill_frame, height=5, width=20, background="green", foreground="black", text="Start Fill")
        Start_fill_button.grid(padx=35,pady=15,row=3,column=0)
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using a loop at all; you simply want to increment a label each time a button is pressed, but stop when the label reaches 5.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're instantiating a button inside the for loop, when you should also be waiting for a callback in the loop. In pseudocode, you might want something like

```
for a in range (start, end):
    # make button as you do
    # ...
    while Start_fill_button.not_clicked ():
        sleep (0.05) # pause while waiting for next check
```